# IPv6 link-local multicast vs. IPv4 broadcast

Tags: ipv6, broadcast

I know that there is no broadcast in IPv6. However, there is the concept of link-local multicast using the `ff02::1` IP address, reaching all hosts in the very same local network.

So what is the difference between `ff02::1` and IPv4 broadcast? Since routers do not forward broadcast packets in IPv4, from my point of view, the behavior of those two concepts is identical?

Comment: Given that `ff02::1` is allowed to be mapped to the broadcast MAC `ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff`, there might be no difference...

Comment: Indeed there is no difference

Comment: …and how does it compare to the IPv4 multicast address `224.0.0.1`?